# Reading User Input until the Answer is right

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a guessing game where the user must figure out a word. I use the module Readline to get the user's input. When the guess of the user is wrong, the question should be asked again. This is my Code:

```
const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

let answer;
const word = "Pancakes"

while (answer != word) {
    readline.question("Guess the word: ", input => {
        answer = input;
        readline.close();
    });
}
```

I've also already tried this:

```
const word = "Pancakes";
let isright = false;

while (!isright) {
    readline.question("Guess the word: ", input => {
        isright = input == word;
        readline.close();
    });
}
```

It has the same result: the console flashes "Guess the word: ", so I would assume the loop just continues before even getting the user's input. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

It's because while is `synchronous` and `readline.question` is asynchronous. You need to Either recursively call the question. Or Need to set a `prompt` and recursively prompt for another one and so on.

```
const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

const word = "Pancakes"
readline.setPrompt('Guess the word: ');
readline.prompt();

readline.on('line', function(input) {
  if(input !== word){
    readline.prompt();
  }else{
    readline.close()
  }
}).on('close', function() {
    console.log('Closed');
    process.exit(0);
});
```